# Rows and columns Bootstrap, independant column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns, css-tables, disqus

I'm facing a problem with Bootstrap in my application. I'll try to be clear as much as I can :

I have 2 columns, in the first one I've got a table on the first half and a disqus comment system in the other half.
In the second column I simply have an other table on the first half. The second half is blank.

Here's a picture

[image: visualisation]

The problem I'm facing actually is when I add comment in the disqus comment system, the second column (with the TABLE2) is going down because the disqus block is getting longer.

What I want is to let disqus sytem getting longer without affecting the location of TABLE2.
I simply want my TABLE2 to stay under my TABLE even if the disqus block is long.

here's the code :

```
.row-fluid
  %h2= "Title ..."
  .span5
      %table
        %thead
          %tr
            %th= "test"
            %th= "test"
            %th= "test"
            %th= "test"
            %th= "test"
            %th= "test"
        %tbody
          = render @something
  .span6
    #disqus_thread
    :javascript
      var disqus_shortname = 'test';
      (function() {
          var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
          dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
          (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
      })();

.row-fluid
  %h2= "test"
  .span5
      %table.table.table-striped#myTable2.tablesorter
        %thead
          %tr
            %th= "test"
            %th= "test"
            %th= "test"
            %th= "test"
            %th= "test"
            %th= "test"
        %tbody
          = render @something
```

I hope I made it clear.

Comment: Add `overflow:auto` in the second half of first column. It will show scroll bar wen the content of that part gets longer

Comment: It's not working actually :/

Comment: Can you show the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange your html structure as follows:

```
<!-- Main Wrapper -->
<div class='row-fluid'>

   <!-- Table Structure Wrapper -->
   <div class='span5'>

         <h2>Table 1</h2>
         <table>

         </table>  

         <h2>Table 2</h2>
         <table>

         </table>  

   </div>

   <!-- DISQUs Comments wrapper -->
   <div class='span6'>

   </div>

</div>
```

You can use CSS to manage the required spacing between tables and other stuffs.